# Will multiplayer games in Magic 2015 unlock cards?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

In previous iterations of the Magic 20XX: Duels of the Planeswalkers games, victory in a multiplayer game (and a single player / campaign game) would reward you with an unlocked card for the deck you were playing.

This made sense, as in previous iterations, players chose from a selection of pre-built decks (much like a purchased 'starter' deck in the tabletop game,) and could only increase available cards *for* that deck by winning duels.

Magic 2014's Sealed Play mode was an exception - you'd unlock booster packs, for use in your Sealed Play library which in turn was used to construct Sealed Play decks, which could only be played against other Sealed Play decks and not standard decks.

Magic 2015 operates under a sort of hybrid format - you still start with a predefined deck, but it's customised in the style of Magic 2014's Sealed Play, i.e. completion of single player duels rewards you with a booster pack, which enters your card pool, out of which you customise your starting deck or create new ones.

However, based on my experience thus far with multiplayer games in Magic 2015, there doesn't appear to be a tangible reward - when you win a match, you are returned to the main menu and recieve no notification of a booster or unlocked card.

The only discussion I could find on the subject ([on the Steam forums, via Google](http://steamcommunity.com/app/255420/discussions/0/43099721350981504/?l=norwegian)) was inconclusive; none of the reviews I've read have mentioned this.

Are there any conditions (such as a certain stage of completion in the campaign) in which winning a multiplayer game will reward you with cards for your deck(s), or are single player campaign/explore duels now the **only** way in which cards can be unlocked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes -** winning a multiplayer game does in fact reward you with a booster pack (by the looks of it, for your current plane / set in the campaign) - but the game doesn't make it very clear.

After winning a game, if you go to the Decks screen on the main menu, you'll see a new booster pack waiting for you to unwrap it. You'll then recieve a couple of cards in your card pool, to be combined into your existing deck, made into new decks, or just to read and enjoy.

Comment: What I find cool is that you can play multiple games and not have to open the boosters till the end of the streak. After a good streak with my mono-green, I got to open 5 "victory" packs, one after another. Ahhhh, the value...